# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState') when implementing DragDropContext in react

Tags: reactjs, draggable

I am trying to implement a drag and drop list, I installed react-beautiful-dnd en added the list of items, set state to listItems, implemented DragDropContext and added a function onDrageComplete but the error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState').

```
    import { usePreloadedQuery } from 'react-relay/hooks';
    import graphql from 'babel-plugin-relay/macro';
    import { DragDropContext, Draggable, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
    import { useState } from 'react';
    
    
    export const listItems = [ 
  { id: '1', label: 'assignedTasks' },
  { id: '2', label: 'manualProgress' },
  { id: '3', label: 'news' },
  { id: '4', label: 'notifications' },
  { id: '5', label: 'documentFavorites' },
   ];

    
    
    
    const query = graphql`
      query DashboardSettingsQuery {
        currentMember {
          organisation {
            dashboardSettings
          }
        }
      }
    `;
    
    export default function DashboardSettings(props) {
      console.log(props);
      const data = usePreloadedQuery(query, props.prepared.dashboardSettingsQuery);
      const [dragDropList, setDragDropList] = useState(listItems);  
      console.log(data);
    
      const onDragComplete = (result) => {
        if (!result.destination) return;
      
        const arr = [...dragDropList];
      
        //Changing the position of Array element
        let removedItem = arr.splice(result.source.index, 1)[0];
        arr.splice(result.destination.index, 0, removedItem);
      
        //Updating the list
        setDragDropList(arr);
      };
    
      return(
        <>
        <h1>dashboardSettings</h1>
        <div className="container">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="header">Horizontal Drag and Drop List</div>
    
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragComplete}>
          <Droppable droppableId="drag-drop-list" direction="horizontal">
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
              <div
                className="drag-drop-list-container"
                {...provided.droppableProps}
                ref={provided.innerRef}
              >
                {dragDropList.map((item, index) => (
                  <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.label} index={index}>
                    {(provided) => (
                      <div
                        className="item-card"
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                      >
                        <span className="material-symbols-outlined">
                          drag_indicator
                        </span>
                        <div className="char-avatar">{item.label.charAt(0)}</div>
                        <p className="label">{item.label}</p>
                      </div>
                    )}
                  </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
              </div>
            )}
          </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
      </div>
    </div>;
    </>
      );
    }
```

Error:

```
[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState')
useState (vendors-node_modules_react-beautiful-dnd_dist_react-beautiful-dnd_esm_js.chunk.js:43660)
useMemoOne (vendors-node_modules_react-beautiful-dnd_dist_react-beautiful-dnd_esm_js.chunk.js:46187)
DragDropContext (vendors-node_modules_react-beautiful-dnd_dist_react-beautiful-dnd_esm_js.chunk.js:8849)
renderWithHooks (bundle.js:67613)
mountIndeterminateComponent (bundle.js:71278)
callCallback (bundle.js:55409)
dispatchEvent
invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:55458)
invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:55520)
beginWork$1 (bundle.js:78533)
performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:77666)
workLoopSync (bundle.js:77579)
renderRootSync (bundle.js:77548)
recoverFromConcurrentError (bundle.js:76956)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (bundle.js:76857)
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
workLoop (bundle.js:126091)
flushWork (bundle.js:126065)
performWorkUntilDeadline (bundle.js:126349)
```

Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: Providing the complete error stacktrace would be very helpful

Comment: @felixyadomi I edited the question.  Can this further help with fixing the issue?